# jQuery code does not work in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using basic tabs function. If I try to add any other code in any of the tab except first one, it does not seem to work. For example, in following code, I am trying to use a plugin to style the select box. If the select box is in first tab, then it works, if it is in the select tab, then it does not. This is probably because of some jQuery loading sequance, but I cannot find any error in the Firebug console.

Please check this **demo** to see the error:

http://jsfiddle.net/qpv6x/

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });

   $('select.style').customSelect();

});
```

Comment: Log a bug with the person that wrote customSelect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, `customSelect();` cant calculate the correct width for the `select` because it is hidden. Move `$('select.style').customSelect();` to before your `$('#tabs div').hide();`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('select.style').customSelect();

    $('#tabs div').hide();
    $('#tabs div:first').show();
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active');

    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#tabs div').hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

Secondly give your tab a position:

```
#tabs div {
    background: #FFFFCC;
    clear: both;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position:relative; /* <-- HERE */
}
```

Works fine for me now in Chrome [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qpv6x/2/)

Comment: Can you explain why `relative` positioning is required?

Comment: `customSelect` works by absolutely positioning the `select` and the 'fake' `select`. You need to position the tabs so that the `select` can be positioned properly within it

Comment: As a side note, I've had issues with this plugin and IE7 in the past. The positioning is sometimes way off. To get around this I usually wrap the select in a relatively positioned span